# Unable to see 'Transactions' section in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a production site in which my transactions are all recorded in google analytics correctly. Recently we have decided to create a staging environment which will be a replica of production. For this staging environment I created a new google account and hooked  it up with Anaytics and Google tag manager. I then updated the code  in staging environment to use this UA and GTM account ids.

When I look at my staging GA dashboard now, I see data, however I do not see a 'transactions' heading under 'ecommerce' and there is nowhere I can see my transactions. I have enabled 'ecommerce' for this GA dashboard from Account > Settings.  Is there anything else I need to configure to see transactions in the dashboard?

Comment: Just to confirm, your problem is not that you do not see any data, your problem is that the relevant menu item does not appear in the Conversions/E-Commerce section of the menu?

Comment: @EikePierstorff that is correct

Comment: I am just curious, did you ever find a solution? Because it sounds like this just shouldn't happen, and it would be interesting to hear what was going on.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Unfortunately I did not get a solution. However I noticed that in my staging GA, Under Ecommerce > Sales Performance  I see the same report as I see under Ecommerce > Transactions in production. Maybe some kind of configuration issue but I since I got the same report I have not dug around more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official GTM dataLayer GA Enhanced Ecommerce spec:
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce

Transactions are referred to as "purchase":
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases

```
<script>
dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': 'T12345',                         // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
        'affiliation': 'Online Store',
        'revenue': '35.43',                     // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
        'tax':'4.90',
        'shipping': '5.99',
        'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
      },
      'products': [{                            // List of productFieldObjects.
        'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',     // Name or ID is required.
        'id': '12345',
        'price': '15.25',
        'brand': 'Google',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'variant': 'Gray',
        'quantity': 1,
        'coupon': ''                            // Optional fields may be omitted or set to empty string.
       },
    ...
```

**The spec documentation isn't of the highest quality, so for a happy implementation I recommend the following best practices**
[dataLayer.push not working after GTM script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625973/datalayer-push-not-working-after-gtm-script#answer-51629320)

- Always initialize the dataLayer
- Always set the "event" property

To facilitate your life even more, you can do:

- Event = `ecommerce_{action}`
- Category = Ecommerce
- Action = {action} (eg purchase, click...)

The event naming convention will allow you to create 1 single GTM trigger (`Event REGEX ecommerce_.*`) and therefore 1 single tag to capture all your Ecommerce events (having to create separate triggers/tags for each Ecommerce action is unnecessary and painful)

Once that's done, create a GTM Google Analytics Event tag with the above trigger, and enable Ecommerce in the GA settings:

[image]